# Cambiar icono y volver al mismo en un onClick de Android

Tags: java, android, android-widget

me encuentro desarrollando una app de android. Una de las imágenes, es un botón que redirecciona a una tarea determinada. Me gustaría que cuando realizo clic, por un segundo, haga efecto de que esta pulsado y vuelva a su estado normal.

Tengo ya preparado el icono sin pulsar y pulsado.

En el evento onclick de la imagen, si lo programo así no hay problema:

```
ImageView imagen=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgcorreo);


    imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.correo2);
```

Tras ello, quiero que vuelva a la imagen anterior, que es esta:

`R.drawable.correo2`

Alguna sugerencia para que haga todo ello?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: implementaste el onTouchListener a tu imageView? si copias el código exactamente como lo tengo debe funcionar sin problema, que problema encontraste al implementarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues probando el código me fijé que el ACTION_UP no estaba siendo llamado y encontré la solución aquí https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799839/motionevent-action-up-not-called, con delvolver true estaría resuelto:

```
imagen.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.correo2);
                }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagen_actual);
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Lo probé y funciona a la perfección, un saludo.

Comment: Gracias pero no funciona :(

Comment: ESTUPENDO!!! CON EL TRUE ESTA PERFECTO!! MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS A TODOS :)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar un selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/imagen_normal"/>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/imagen_pulsada" android:state_pressed="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/imagen_pulsada" android:state_hovered="true"/>
</selector>
```

Guarda este archivo en tu carpeta drawable y asígnaselo a tu vista.

Un saludo.

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia, pero como le añado ese selector a la imagen?

Comment: No te preocupes que te lo explico.
Tienes que guardar este fichero en la carpeta drawable (ponle que lo nombras como my_selector.xml). Después se lo asignas al ImageView como si fuera una imagen normal. En tu caso: imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_selector);

Comment: Gracias! me lo apunto  que resulta muy interesante!

Answer (score 1):

Existen varias opciones si vas a determinar un icono nuevo al dar click en el ImageView puedes usar un OnTouchListener y cuando se de click al boton, ejecute el evento [ACTION_DOWN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_DOWN)  y cambias el icono, al liberar el botón se ejecuta el evento [ACTION_UP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_UP) y cambias al icono inicial:

```
ImageView imagen=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgcorreo); 
    imagen.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            switch(event.getAction())
                            {
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
        imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.correo2);
                                break;
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
       imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.imgcorreo);
                                break;
                            }
                            return true;
                        }

                    });
```

muy importante definir `return true;`

Otra opción es usando un [selector](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html).

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/correo2" android:android:state_pressed     ="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/correo2" android:android:state_selected     ="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/imgcorreo" android:state_selected="false" />
</selector>
```

defines este .xml dentro de la carpeta `res/drawable` y lo asignas como drawable en tu ImageView.

importante saber que si defines el drawable directamente en el layout de tu ImageView debes agregar la propiedad

```
android:clickable="true"
```

ejemplo:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgcorreo"
        android:clickable="true"
         ...
         ...
         ...
        android:src="@drawable/mi_selector"
</ImageView>
```

Ambas formas son validas para poder realizar algo como esto, al dar click al botón cambia el icono y al liberar cambia a su imagen original.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que si mi respuesta no el funcionó esta tampoco ^^. Un saludo

Comment: Es obvio que tu respuesta no va a funcionar si estas definiendo otra imagen que no existe al liberar el boton =P.

Comment: ¿te refieres a R.drawable.imagen_actual? esta claro que no existe es el quien tiene cambiar imagen_actual por la imagen que desee

Comment: vamos a preguntar, no debería tener ningun problema si define el recurso correcto. =)

Comment: Había que devolver true y ya funciona ^^. Un cordial saludo Elenasys.

Comment: ok ya veo, para consumir el evento entonces seguramente es eso! =0

Answer (score 0):

tengo una duda. En lugar de que se trate de un ImageView. Puede aplicarse este bloque de código:

```
 imagen.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.correo2);
                }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagen_actual);
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
```

a un boton flotante?